# strtotime function for hours more than 24

Tags: php

Hello I am trying to compare a time during with Hours:Minutes:Seconds format using strtotime function but there is a probleme if Hours is more than 24

PHP Code:

```
$time_duration_1 = '102:44:18';
$time_duration_2 = '87:42:19';

if(strtotime($time_duration_1) > strtotime($time_duration_2))
{
   return true;
}else{
   return false;
}
```

Is there any handy function for that kind of situation? or shall I do the checking manually hard coded?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function to calculate your hours, minutes and seconds:

```
function formatHours($time){
    $date = explode(':', $time);
    return ($date[0]*60*60)+($date[1]*60)+$date[2];
}

if(formatHours($time_duration_1) > formatHours($time_duration_2)){
// ......
```

Comment: Since you are just comparing, this is probably a better solution - mine is a bit overkill :P

Answer (score 1):

The way I'd solve that would be with `mktime`:

```
function getTimeFromString($time){
    $time = explode(':', $time);
    return mktime($time[0], $time[1], $time[2]);
}

if(getTimeFromString($time_duration_1) > getTimeFromString($time_duration_2)){
```